# how to keep changing from img to anchor and div background from reformatting output

Tags: css, image, html

I have moved an image from inside a div to being the background of the div so that using different CSS files I can show different images.  The problem I'm running into is that simply by adding an anchor around the div, the format is being thrown off.

Here is what I had:

```
<div class="logoWrap">
<a href="\">
  <img src="@Html.SvccCdnPreAppend("/Images/silicon-valley-code-camp.png")" class="border-None"></a>
 </div>

#header .logoInfoBar .logoWrap {
  padding: 6px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is what I tried changing it to.  If I don't add the anchor, then the format is correct.  I don't understand how adding an anchor tag can affect formatting.

```
 <a href="/"><div class="logoWrap"></div></a>

#header .logoInfoBar .logoWrap {
  background-image: url(/Images/silicon-valley-code-camp.png);
  width: 350px;
  height: 57px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  padding: 6px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you show this in a jsfiddle with enough code

Comment: what do you mean by formatting. possible `img` tag has `padding|margin` pusing things out. try `padding:0 margin:0`

Answer (score 0):

And what happens when you try something like

```
<a href="/" class="logoWrap"></a>
```

?